# JSONDecodeError in SimpleJSON module when passing curl request to RASA NLU

Tags: python, curl, rasa-nlu

when i am trying to send query to the server it returns this error:

the query code is:

```
curl -X POST localhost:5000/parse -d '{"q":"I am looking for Chinese food"}' | python -m json.tool 

File "C:\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\simplejson\decoder.py", line 400, in raw_decode
            return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
        simplejson.scanner.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I am simply following the instructions from [here](http://rasa-nlu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html).

Comment: Then, the `curl` request does not return JSON. Have checked the output of the `curl` call without the pipe?

Comment: How to do thar sir,
I have just started rasa today.

Comment: Remove the `|` and everything after it from the command line!

Comment: yes...the output is:
`<html><head><title>web.Server Traceback (most recent call last)</title></head><body><b>web.Server Traceback (most recent call last):</b>

<div>
  <style type="text/css">
    div.error {
      color: red;
      font-family: Verdana, Arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    div {
      font-family: Verdana, Arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

    div.stackTrace {
    }

    div.frame {
      padding: 1em;
      background: white;
      border-bottom: thin black dashed;
    }`

Comment: Add it to your question as *code* formatted block.

Comment: `curl -X POST localhost:5000/parse -d r'{"q":"I am looking for Chinese food"}' | python -m json.tool`  Try passing the the JSON as a raw string.

Comment: @KunalMukherjee:
Error my friend.

`C:\Users\anish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\rasa_nlu>curl -X POST localhost:5000/parse -d r'{"q":"I am looking for Chinese food"}' | python -m json.tool`

`  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  5626  100  5590  100    36  22360    144 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 22360
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Comment: Are you by any chance running windows?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
curl -X POST localhost:5000/parse -d '{"q":"I am looking for Chinese food"}' **--header "Content-Type: application/json"**
```

Server will recognise the data sent as JSON